Split column data into new columns
I have a MySQL table in which the field_value column consists of multiple types of information such as category(542),subcategory(11),priority(700) identified using the value_id



t_id
field_value
field_value_id




112233
Event
542


112233
Event
542


112233
Information
11


112233
Information
11


112233
Medium
700


112233
Medium
700


998877
Renewal
542


998877
Renewal
542


998877
Telephone
11


998877
Telephone
11


998877
Low
700


998877
Low
700



I need to create three separate columns and fill in each row with the value so it looks like this:



t_id
field_value
field_value_id
category
subcategory
priority




112233
Event
542
Event
Information
Medium


112233
Event
542
Event
Information
Medium


112233
Information
11
Event
Information
Medium


112233
Information
11
Event
Information
Medium


112233
Medium
700
Event
Information
Medium


112233
Medium
700
Event
Information
Medium


998877
Renewal
542
Renewal
Telephone
Low


998877
Renewal
542
Renewal
Telephone
Low


998877
Telephone
11
Renewal
Telephone
Low


998877
Telephone
11
Renewal
Telephone
Low


998877
Low
700
Renewal
Telephone
Low


998877
Low
700
Renewal
Telephone
Low



How can I do this with a SELECT statement?
I used a CASE statement like this:
MAX(CASE WHEN `field_value_id` = 542 THEN field_value ELSE "" END) AS `category`

This creates a new column and fills in the values but only where the value_id matches, but
I need this to fill in the entire column.

You need to add partition by as well, in order to get the result,
SELECT 
    t_id,
    field_value,
    field_value_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_value_id = 542 THEN field_value ELSE NULL END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY t_id) AS category,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_value_id = 11 THEN field_value ELSE NULL END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY t_id) AS subcategory,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_value_id = 700 THEN field_value ELSE NULL END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY t_id) AS priority
FROM 
    my_table;

Refer this for full execution: dbfiddle

Thank you very much for your help. this resolved my issue.
